# Why flutter Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(()) not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a small app here, i will check buildNumber of current app and compare to my remote api data, based on this condition i will show the user interfaces.
I have home and updateApp screen where home is the normal webview screen and UpdateApp is a screen where user is required to update the new version of my app.
But condition satisfies but update screen is not showing.

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, use_build_context_synchronously, unrelated_type_equality_checks, unused_element
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:webview_test/models/app_version.dart';
import 'package:webview_test/services/remote_service.dart';
import 'package:webview_test/views/update_app.dart';
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  bool isLoading = true;
  double webProgress = 0;
  bool isLoaded = false;
  List<AppVersion>? appVersions;
  int buildNumber = 0;
  late String packageName;

  @override
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen((double progress) {
      setState(() {
        this.webProgress = progress;
      });
      print("The progress is $progress");
    });

    getVersions();
    getBuild();
  }

  //Fetching remote data for app versions.

  getVersions() async {
    appVersions = await RemoteService().getAppVersion();
    if (appVersions != null) {
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }

//getting app information to compare remote app versions.

  getBuild() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    packageName = packageInfo.packageName;
    buildNumber = int.parse(packageInfo.buildNumber);
    print("build number is $buildNumber");

    if (buildNumber == 1) {
      print("Build number is $buildNumber");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));

    return MaterialApp(
      home: buildNumber == 1
          ? proceedToUpdate(context)
          : SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                body: WillPopScope(
                    onWillPop: () async {
                      if (await flutterWebViewPlugin.canGoBack()) {
                        flutterWebViewPlugin.goBack();

                        return false;
                      } else {
                        SystemNavigator.pop();
                        return true;
                      }
                    },
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned.fill(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              webProgress < 1
                                  ? SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                                        value: webProgress,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : SizedBox(),
                              Expanded(
                                child: WebviewScaffold(
                                  url: "https://google.com",
                                  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                                  withLocalStorage: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                              // isLoading
                              //     ? Center(
                              //         child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              //       )
                              //     : Stack(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  proceedToUpdate(context) {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UpdateApp()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **context** in `Navigator.of(context).push(...)` isn't correct.

You're trying to navigate outside `build(BuildContext context)`, so it won't work. Function `build(BuildContext context)` is the place where it build your mobile interface - UI screen.

Now in your StatefulWidget `MyHomePage` -> `initState()` -> `getBuild()` -> `_proceedToUpdate()` -> `Navigator.of(context).push(...)`. The variable **context** in your Navigator command is not context of your screen UI. Even though function `_proceedToUpdate()` can run, it cannot navigate.

You may try to show an dialog. Each dialog also has a context. You can show an dialog and then navigate to somewhere when press "OK" button. It'll success.

Good luck!

**Update:**

Seems like you don't want to show any dialog, therefore we need another approach. You could check the build version in `main() async {}`. Then pass value buildNumber to somewhere (directly pass to MyApp() or use singleton to make it more professional :D). Then you can make it like: `home: _getFirstScreen()`

```
_getFirstScreen() {
  if (buildNumber == 1) return UpdateScreen();
  else return MyHomePage();
}
```

Comment: I want to show without any dialog

Comment: i just update my answer.

Comment: After i try _TypeError (type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?')

Comment: OK haha :D my bad. Move it to main() function, i just update answer

Comment: not working.....

Comment: bro... give me error

Comment: dont worry, im able to help :D

Comment: i updated code. plz check any chances

Comment: :) i never see anyone use StatefulWidget to runApp(). You may give me access to your git, i'll fix for you. Do you accept?

Comment: okay. let me add into git

Comment: nvbien2000@gmail.com

Comment: im getting error for react native so i'm at StackOverflow for hours :D